# How to change method to call for an entity on the PreSerializeEvent?

Tags: php, symfony, events, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have a `Category` entity that contains a bunch of `Assets`. The Category has a `getCount` method that return the amount of assets in it.

I use FosRestBundle and hence JMSSerializerBundle to serialize the Category asset to json. Now, there was a feature change that introduced different kind of assets, e.g. `external` and `internal` ones.

I still want to use the entity serialization, and I thought by creating a `PreSerializeEvent` I actually could do that.

Yet the [docs for the serializer component](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/event_system) are obscure by referring to the relevant part as `do something`

How am I actually supposed to do something here?

What I want to achieve is to change the method that is called if a flag is set. Normal case for the serializer should be to use the `getCount` method, on the other the `getExternalCountOnly` method on the Category object if `getCount` is serialized.

Is this actually possible to do here or am I on the wrong track?

See my `CategorySerializationSubscriber`:

```
<?php
namespace Hn\AssetDbBundle\Listener;

use Hn\AssetDbBundle\Entity\Category;
use Hn\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\PostSerialize;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

/**
 * Class CategorySerializationSubscriber
 * @package Hn\AssetDbBundle\Listener
 */

class CategorySerializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var User $user
     */

    private $user;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, SecurityContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->user = $context->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $logger->critical($this->user->getFullNameOrEmail());
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            [
                'event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize',
                'method' => 'onPreSerialize'
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param PreSerializeEvent $event
     */

    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        $category = $this->getCategoryFromEvent($event);

        if (!$category) {
            $this->logger->info('is not a category, aborting');
            return;
        }

        $userCanViewInternalAsset = $this->user->isAllowedToViewInternalAssets();

        /**
         * How to actually do something?
         * 
         * Pseudocode follows:
         */

        if ($userCanViewInternalAsset) {
            $seriaization->replaceMethod($category, 'getCount', 'getExternalAssetCount');
        } else {
            /**
             * $category->getCount(); remains intact
             */
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param PreSerializeEvent $event
     * @return Category|null
     */

    protected function getCategoryFromEvent(PreSerializeEvent $event) {

        /**
         * @var Category $category
         */

        $category = $event->getObject();

        if (!$category instanceof Category) {
            return null;

        }

        return $category;

    }
}
```

Comment: What if you just add a JMS group to each function - `internal` for `getCount()` and `external` for `getExternalAssetCount()`, then add the appropriate serialization group based on the user's access level?

Comment: @JasonRoman Then I would have to set the group on all instances where I serialize a category. This is also not clear due to dependencies, as Category has relations to other entities as well and may be serialized when those are serialized.  I rather want to avoid that, and have that happen via an event for all serializations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about excluding by default and then using the postSerialize() subscriber to add it with the function you want?  For example:

Define in services.yml (or under `services` in config.yml):

```
category_serialization_subscriber:
    class: Hn\AssetDbBundle\Listener\CategorySerializationSubscriber
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

Then the following, which is modified from your class above:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(array(
        'event'  => 'serializer.post_serialize',
        'class'  => 'Hn\AssetDbBundle\Entity\Category',
        'method' => 'onPostSerialize'
    ));
}

public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
{
    $category = $event->getObject();
    $visitor  = $event->getVisitor();

    if ($this->user->isAllowedToViewInternalAssets()) {
        $visitor->addData('count', $category->getExternalAssetCount());
    } else {
        $visitor->addData('count', $category->getCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: The onPostSerialize does not get called O.o. Is there another tag needed or does the `name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber` still apply?

Comment: I updated my post to show that you need to add this as an event listener so it gets triggered

Comment: Thanks very much for the input, yet still no dice :( It does not even call the onPostSerialize. Could there be a problem with the `Entity.Cateory.yml` configuration?

Comment: You could try removing the `class` part from my `getSubscribedEvents` configuration just to see if your `onPostSerialize` method is being triggered...perhaps add a `$logger->info('test');` inside of it to see if it's getting triggered.

Comment: The logger approach is how I know that the event is not triggered. Removing the class parameter also did not help. The eventSubscriber only gets created (I have a log message in its constructor) but never called. The preSerializer at least got called.

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe there is an an issue of the FosRestBundle doing the serialization and that may not trigger the event.

Comment: I think I gave you the wrong tag name, see edit above: `- { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }`, not `- { name: jms_serializer.post_serialize` }

Comment: Yes, it eventually did. I ran into an issue with `JmsSerializerBundle`, or more to the point its `metadata` dependency where it tried to access Doctrine proxy classes instead of the hydrated entities which caused exceptions in my case. Yet with eager loading the assets from the Category entity, it worked and it is a sufficient solution for my needs. Thank you once again very much for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working - that's very interesting about the proxy classes and hydrated entities with eager loading...I'll keep that in mind for the future if I encounter similar issues